# CommentsController Fails to Post the Comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, comments

I am trying to code a Blog with Ruby on Rails, i came so far to code my Comment Controller, I am a little bit rusty in Ruby so this could actually be the problem (Using old ways of coding?).

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.build(params.permit[:comment])
  @comment.save

  redirect_to(:back)
end
```

Now, it actually works fine, but it simply won't post the comment, it simply says "Posted xyz minutes ago" but the actually Post that is written, is not shown on the page, after sending it to the site. I don't now if this is a db problem, or a code failure (even if, its a code fail ;))!

If you guys need more information about my code, simply ask :)!

Comment: do you mean you see some changes at html page, but they do not contain all the information you would like? provide your `view` code and `new` action code aswell then.

Comment: sorry for the question: Do you mean by view code, the code from the HMTL site, and where can i get the new action code ? Sorry i am new to rails !

Comment: It seems more likely that your code is working fine, but your templates aren't outputting your comment. You can test this by running `rails console`, finding your post, and seeing what comments it has. For instance: `p = Post.find(3)` then `p.comments`

Comment: Thanks Alex, it seems like, its actually registering the comments BUT still outputting the actually comment as "text: nil":  Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."post_id" = ?  [["post_id", 3]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Comment id: 5, post_id: 3, text: nil, created_at: "2014-06-21 10:42:56", updated_at

Comment: tried some other stuff, didn't work still looking like this: http://abload.de/img/bildschirmfoto2014-063rk00.png

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your [`permit`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) call, it should read

```
params.permit(comment: :text)
```

This assumes your Comment model stores the actual comment in the `body` column, and your `params` look like this:

```
{ post_id: 42, comment: { text: "..." } }
```

Also, you should make use of [ActiveRecord's validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) and catch invalid comments like this:

```
def create
  # ...
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, pretty helpful, but my code is actually working, i changed it up to yours. But the Problem (As above listed from Alex) is actually the problem. The DB is registering the comment, but is putting the text to nil, so i actually have no clue where to change that now :E!

Comment: ... that is for various degrees of working. It may register to create a comment, but it ignores the text, because you did not permit the comment's text. I've provided an answer on how to do this.